# How set setting environment with DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE

Tags: python, django, git, server, wsgi

I am new in Python \ Django and I have some question about settings environment. I use git for edit my project and on server I have production project. But when I edit project on local machine I have my own `settings(DATABASE)` so if I pull edited project on server I need to change my settings, so I want to set `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE`, but I don't know what path I must set and where I must allocate my default setting.

This is my hierarchy:

```
wow
├── core
│   ├── admin.py
│   ├── api_views.py
│   ├── apps.py
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── migrations
│   │   ├── 0001_initial.py
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   └── __pycache__
│   ├── models.py
│   ├── __pycache__
│   │   ├── admin.cpython-35.pyc
│   │   ├── api_views.cpython-35.pyc
│   │   ├── __init__.cpython-35.pyc
│   │   ├── models.cpython-35.pyc
│   │   ├── sitemap.cpython-35.pyc
│   │   ├── urls.cpython-35.pyc
│   │   └── views.cpython-35.pyc
│   ├── sitemap.py
│   ├── tests.py
│   ├── urls.py
│   └── views.py
├── manage.py
├── media
│   └── core
│       ├── iUcZCekdW68_FrqsEHv.jpg
│       ├── iUcZCekdW68.jpg
│       ├── qWI5I5NuIeg.jpg
│       ├── server1.png
│       └── server2.png
├── not_found
│   ├── admin.py
│   ├── apps.py
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── migrations
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   └── __pycache__
│   ├── models.py
│   ├── __pycache__
│   │   ├── admin.cpython-35.pyc
│   │   ├── __init__.cpython-35.pyc
│   │   ├── models.cpython-35.pyc
│   │   ├── urls.cpython-35.pyc
│   │   └── views.cpython-35.pyc
│   ├── tests.py
│   ├── urls.py
│   └── views.py
├── requirements.txt
├── settings.py
├── static
│   ├── admin
│   │   ├── css
│   │   ├── fonts
│   │   ├── img
│   │   └── js
│   └── core
│       ├── css
│       ├── img
│       └── js
├── staticfiles
│   ├── admin
│   │   ├── css
│   │   ├── fonts
│   │   ├── img
│   │   └── js
│   └── core
│       ├── css
│       ├── img
│       └── js
├── templates
│   ├── 404.html
│   ├── admin
│   │   ├── base.html
│   │   ├── base_site.html
│   │   └── index.html
│   ├── character.html
│   ├── characters.html
│   ├── checkout.html
│   ├── index.html
│   └── server.html
├── url.xml
└── wow
    ├── gunicorn.conf.py
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── __pycache__
    │   ├── __init__.cpython-35.pyc
    │   ├── settings.cpython-35.pyc
    │   ├── urls.cpython-35.pyc
    │   └── wsgi.cpython-35.pyc
    ├── settings.py
    ├── urls.py
    ├── views.py
    └── wsgi.py
```

What i must do, end where i must write `os.environ["DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE"] = wow.settings,` or something like this?

Comment: You have to set that env var to point to your settings script module (using **_Python_ path syntax**). Check [\[DjangoProject\]: Designating the settings](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/settings/#designating-the-settings) for more details (in your case it could be: `export DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=wow.settings`, assuming that the outer _wow_ (project root?) folder is in the module search path).

Comment: How can i add outer wow to module search path?

Comment: And where would i allocate my settings after `export` command?

Comment: You can launch _python_ from that folder, and it will be added automatically, or you could set the _PYTHONPATH_ env var (from shell) before launching _python_, or you could `sys.path.append` the new path immediately after starting _python_. I don't know what "_allocate my settings_" means.